# How do I pass multiple parameters to a logparser sql query?

Tags: syntax, logparser

Using logparser you can pass on parameters to the query you'd like to run such as:

```
logparser file:query.sql?logs=somewhere\*.log -o:Sql -server:databaseserver 
  -database:database  -createtable:ON -i:IISW3C 
  -iCheckPoint:somewhere\query.lpc -transactionRowCount:200
```

Now I want to pass a second parameter to the sql query but it doesn't seem possible.

```
logparser file:query.sql?a=1&b=2
```

is seen as: a = "1&b=2".
Escaping the character with an accent doesn't work either. Is this a limitation of the logparser tool?

Comment: I'm working this way because i want to run the same query on a series of websites and then create a db table for each website

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Found the answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/adcman/archive/2006/05/15/598149.aspx), use the + character:

```
logparser file:query.sql?a=1+b=2
```